# Creating tabs dynamically in android

Tags: java, android, json, for-loop, android-tablayout

Hi friends please help me out. I am stuck here for more than 2 days and i do not understand whats the error here. My problem is that i am creating the Tabs with icon based on the JSON data here the issue is that icons are coming but they are gone when the remaining data loads in the fragments.but When i removing the adapter then icons are coming and they are visible here i had found a bug that when i comment this line **sticker_tab.setupWithViewPager(sticker_pager);** then everything is working fine but cant move the tab based on the viewpager changing or vice verse
Here is my code :

ChatHistory.java

```
public class ChatHistory extends AppCompatActivity {
@BindView(R.id.chat_his_list)
ListView chat_his_list;
@BindView(R.id.chat_his_toolbar)
Toolbar chat_his_toolbar;
@BindView(R.id.sendmsg)
EmojiconEditText sendmsg;
OkHttpClient chatclient = new OkHttpClient();
public static final String BroadCastAction = "chat";
BroadcastReceiver chatreceiver;
ArrayList<Chat_Pojo> chatlist = new ArrayList<>();
Chat_History_Adapter chat_history_adapter;
@BindView(R.id.smiley)
ImageView smiley;
EmojIconActions emojIcon;
@BindView(R.id.mainviewgroup)
RelativeLayout mainviewgroup;
@BindView(R.id.goondate)
Button goondate;
@BindView(R.id.buyagift_layout)
LinearLayout buyagift_layout;
boolean buyagiftclicked = false;
@BindView(R.id.sticker_tab)
TabLayout sticker_tab;
@BindView(R.id.sticker_pager)
ViewPager sticker_pager;
Chat_Sticker_Adapter chat_sticker_adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chat_history);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setSupportActionBar(chat_his_toolbar);
    assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    chat_history_adapter = new Chat_History_Adapter(ChatHistory.this, chatlist);
    chat_his_list.setStackFromBottom(true);
    chat_his_list.setTranscriptMode(chat_his_list.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_NORMAL);
    chat_his_list.setAdapter(chat_history_adapter);
    emojIcon = new EmojIconActions(this, mainviewgroup, sendmsg, smiley);
    emojIcon.setIconsIds(R.mipmap.keyboard_chat, R.mipmap.smiley_chat);
    Session.pushnotification(getApplicationContext());
    stickermethd();
    emojIcon.setKeyboardListener(new EmojIconActions.KeyboardListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyboardOpen() {
            Constant.l("Open");
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyboardClose() {
            emojIcon.closeEmojIcon();
            Constant.l("Close");
        }
    });
    emojIcon.ShowEmojIcon();
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("mtype")) {
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("popup")) {
            gondatepopup(getIntent().getStringExtra("oppusername").replace("$", " "), getIntent().getStringExtra("profileimg"));
        }
        chathistory(Session.getUserID(getApplicationContext()), getIntent().getStringExtra("oid"));
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("oppusername").replace("$", " "));
        Session.oppuserimg(getApplicationContext(), getIntent().getStringExtra("profileimg"));
    } else {
        chathistory(Session.getUserID(getApplicationContext()), getIntent().getStringExtra("oid"));
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("oppusername").replace("$", " "));
    }
    chat_his_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (chatlist.get(position).getType().equals("image")) {
                Intent chatimageintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Chat_Image.class);
                chatimageintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                chatimageintent.putExtra("chatimage", chatlist.get(position).getMessage());
                startActivity(chatimageintent);
            }

        }
    });


    chatreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getStringExtra("msg").equals("gondate")) {
                gondatepopup(getIntent().getStringExtra("oppusername").replace("$", " "), Session.getoppuserimg(getApplicationContext()).replace(",", ""));
            } else if (intent.getStringExtra("msg").equals("Your Go on date Rejected")) {
                goondate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                chat_history_adapter.addmsg(intent.getStringExtra("sid"), intent.getStringExtra("msg"), intent.getStringExtra("type"));
            }

        }
    };
    IntentFilter intfil = new IntentFilter(BroadCastAction);
    registerReceiver(chatreceiver, intfil);
    /*buyagift_layout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Constant.getScreenWidth(getApplicationContext()) / 4));*/


}

private void gondatepopup(String username, String userimage) {
    goondate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    final Dialog gondatadialog = new Dialog(ChatHistory.this);
    gondatadialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    gondatadialog.setContentView(R.layout.gondate_dialog);
    gondatadialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    gondatadialog.setCancelable(false);
    TextView name = (TextView) gondatadialog.findViewById(R.id.name);
    name.setText(username);
    CircleImageView profile_image = (CircleImageView) gondatadialog.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(userimage).into(profile_image);
    FancyButton accept = (FancyButton) gondatadialog.findViewById(R.id.accept);
    accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gondatadialog.dismiss();
            acceptdialog();
            gondatedisplay();
        }
    });
    FancyButton decline = (FancyButton) gondatadialog.findViewById(R.id.decline);
    decline.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            goondate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sendmsgmethod("Your Go on date Rejected");
            gondatadialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    gondatadialog.show();

}

@OnClick(R.id.gift)
public void gift() {
    if (!buyagiftclicked) {
        buyagiftclicked = true;
        buyagift_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        buyagiftclicked = false;
        buyagift_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

private void chathistory(String senderid, String receiverid) {
    Constant.showloader(ChatHistory.this);
    HttpUrl.Builder chthisurl = HttpUrl.parse(url + "chat&task=getchat").newBuilder();
    chthisurl.addQueryParameter("sender_id", senderid);
    chthisurl.addQueryParameter("reciever_id", receiverid);
    Request chathistoryreq = new Request.Builder().url(chthisurl.build().toString()).build();
    Constant.l(chthisurl.build().toString());
    chatclient.newCall(chathistoryreq).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Constant.l(e.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    final JSONObject chathisobj = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                    JSONArray chathisarray = chathisobj.getJSONArray("text");
                    for (int i = 0; i < chathisarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject chathisarrayobj = chathisarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        final Chat_Pojo chat_pojo = new Chat_Pojo();
                        chat_pojo.setMessage(chathisarrayobj.getString("message"));
                        chat_pojo.setRid(chathisarrayobj.getString("rid"));
                        chat_pojo.setSid(chathisarrayobj.getString("sid"));
                        chat_pojo.setType(chathisarrayobj.getString("type"));
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (chathisobj.has("godate")) {
                                    goondate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                                chatlist.add(chat_pojo);
                                chat_history_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Constant.l(e.toString());
                }
                Constant.dismissloader();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Session.removepushnotification(getApplicationContext());
    Intent chathistoryintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main_Screen.class);
    chathistoryintent.putExtra("chathis", "chathis");
    startActivity(chathistoryintent);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Session.removepushnotification(getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Session.removepushnotification(getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Session.pushnotification(getApplicationContext());
}

@OnClick(R.id.goondate)
public void goondate() {
    Request sendmsgreq = new Request.Builder().url(url + "godate&task=send&sender_id=" + Session.getUserID(getApplicationContext()) + "&reciever_id=" + getIntent().getStringExtra("oid")).build();
    chatclient.newCall(sendmsgreq).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Constant.l(e.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            Constant.l(response.toString());
            try {
                JSONObject sendobj = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                if (sendobj.getString("status").equals("Success")) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            goondate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(chatreceiver);
    super.onDestroy();

}

private void acceptdialog() {
    final Dialog gondateacceptdialog = new Dialog(ChatHistory.this);
    gondateacceptdialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    gondateacceptdialog.setContentView(R.layout.gondate_accept);
    gondateacceptdialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    gondateacceptdialog.setCancelable(false);
    RecyclerView accept_list = (RecyclerView) gondateacceptdialog.findViewById(R.id.accept_list);
    accept_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ChatHistory.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    final FastItemAdapter<GonDate_Accept_Adapter> gonacceptadapter = new FastItemAdapter<>();
    accept_list.setAdapter(gonacceptadapter);
    Request acceptrequest = new Request.Builder().url(url + "godatelist").build();
    chatclient.newCall(acceptrequest).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Constant.l(e.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            try {
                JSONObject acceptjsonobj = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                JSONArray acceptarray = acceptjsonobj.getJSONArray("list");
                for (int i = 0; i < acceptarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject acceptobjarray = acceptarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Gson acceptgson = new Gson();
                    final GonDate_Accept_Adapter goacceptadapter = acceptgson.fromJson(String.valueOf(acceptobjarray), GonDate_Accept_Adapter.class);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            gonacceptadapter.add(goacceptadapter);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    gonacceptadapter.withOnClickListener(new FastAdapter.OnClickListener<GonDate_Accept_Adapter>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClick(View v, IAdapter<GonDate_Accept_Adapter> adapter, GonDate_Accept_Adapter item, int position) {
            sendmsgmethod(item.getAceepttype());
            gondateacceptdialog.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
    });
    gondateacceptdialog.show();

}

@OnClick(R.id.attachment)
public void attachment() {
    TedBottomPicker bottomSheetDialogFragment = new TedBottomPicker.Builder(ChatHistory.this)
            .setOnImageSelectedListener(new TedBottomPicker.OnImageSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageSelected(Uri uri) {
                    try {
                        Bitmap attachbitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(ChatHistory.this.getContentResolver(), uri);
                        attach(attachbitmap);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Constant.l(e.toString());
                    }
                }
            })
            .setPeekHeight(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / 2)
            .create();

    bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager());
}


@OnClick(R.id.smiley)
public void smiley() {
    emojIcon.ShowEmojIcon();
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imagebytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String uploadencodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imagebytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return uploadencodedImage;
}

private void attach(Bitmap bitmapimage) {
    Constant.showloader(ChatHistory.this);
    RequestBody formbody = new FormBody.Builder().add("document1", getStringImage(bitmapimage)).build();
    Request attachrequest = new Request.Builder().url(url + "chatdocument&task=send&sender_id=" + Session.getUserID(getApplicationContext()) + "&reciever_id=" + getIntent().getStringExtra("oid")).post(formbody).build();
    chatclient.newCall(attachrequest).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Constant.l(e.toString());
            Constant.dismissloader();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            try {
                final JSONObject attachobj = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            chat_history_adapter.addmsg(Session.getUserID(getApplicationContext()), attachobj.getString("url"), "image");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Constant.dismissloader();
        }
    });
}


@OnClick(R.id.send)
public void send() {
    if (sendmsg.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        Constant.t(getApplicationContext(), "Please type message");
    } else {
        String msg = sendmsg.getText().toString();
        sendmsgmethod(msg);
    }

}

private void gondatedisplay() {
    Constant.showloader(ChatHistory.this);
    Request gonreqstatus = new Request.Builder().url(url + "changestatus&sender_id=" + Session.getUserID(getApplicationContext()) + "&reciever_id=" + getIntent().getStringExtra("oid") + "&status=0").build();
    chatclient.newCall(gonreqstatus).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Constant.l(e.toString());
            Constant.dismissloader();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            Constant.l(response.body().string());
            Constant.dismissloader();
        }
    });
}

private void sendmsgmethod(final String sendsmsg) {
    chat_his_list.setSelection(chat_history_adapter.getCount() - 1);
    String message = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(sendsmsg);
    message = message.replace("\\", "$");
    Request sendmsgreq = new Request.Builder().url(url + "chat&task=send&sender_id=" + Session.getUserID(getApplicationContext()) + "&reciever_id=" + getIntent().getStringExtra("oid") + "&message=" + message).build();
    chatclient.newCall(sendmsgreq).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Constant.l(e.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            Constant.l(response.toString());
            try {
                JSONObject sendobj = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                if (sendobj.getString("status").equals("Success")) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            chat_history_adapter.addmsg(Session.getUserID(getApplicationContext()), sendsmsg, "text");
                            sendmsg.setText("");
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Constant.l(e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Session.removepushnotification(getApplicationContext());
            Intent chathistoryintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main_Screen.class);
            chathistoryintent.putExtra("chathis", "chathis");
            startActivity(chathistoryintent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void stickermethd() {
    Request stickerrequest = new Request.Builder().url(url + "gifts&facebook_id=" + Session.getUserID(getApplicationContext())).build();
    Constant.l(url + "gifts&facebook_id=" + Session.getUserID(getApplicationContext()));
    chatclient.newCall(stickerrequest).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Constant.l(e.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            try {
                JSONObject startobj = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                JSONObject giftobj = startobj.getJSONObject("giftcategories");
                final JSONArray giftarray = giftobj.getJSONArray("giftmenu");
                for (int i = 0; i < giftarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject gigtarrayboj=giftarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(gigtarrayboj.getString("giftcatimage")).getContent();
                    Constant.l(giftarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("giftcatimage"));
                    final Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "caticon");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                sticker_tab.addTab(sticker_tab.newTab().setIcon(d));
                                Constant.l("Tab Count===>" + String.valueOf(sticker_tab.getTabCount()));
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Constant.l(e.toString());
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        chat_sticker_adapter = new Chat_Sticker_Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), giftarray);
                        sticker_pager.setAdapter(chat_sticker_adapter);
                        sticker_tab.setupWithViewPager(sticker_pager);
                    }
                });

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

}
Chat_Sticker_Adapter.java

```
public class Chat_Sticker_Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    JSONArray jsonArray;

    public Chat_Sticker_Adapter(FragmentManager fm,JSONArray jsonArray) {
        super(fm);
        this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return Buy_A_Gift_Fragment.getInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return jsonArray.length();
    }


    /*public View getTabView(int position) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_tab, null);
        CircleImageView img = (CircleImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tab_icon);
        try {
            Glide.with(context).load(jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("giftcatimage")).into(img);
            Constant.l(jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("giftcatimage"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return v;
    }*/
}
```

Fragment of the tab

```
public class Buy_A_Gift_Fragment extends Fragment {
    @BindView(R.id.buyagift_recyclerview)
    RecyclerView buyagift_recyclerview;
    Buy_a_gift_adapter buyAGiftAdapterFastItemAdapter;
    ArrayList<StickerImage_Icon> stickerarray = new ArrayList<>();


    public Buy_A_Gift_Fragment() {
    }

    public static Fragment getInstance(int position) {
        Buy_A_Gift_Fragment otcFragment = new Buy_A_Gift_Fragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("position", position);
        otcFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return otcFragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.buyagift_frag, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        buyAGiftAdapterFastItemAdapter = new Buy_a_gift_adapter(getActivity(), stickerarray);
        LinearLayoutManager buygridlayoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        buyagift_recyclerview.setLayoutManager(buygridlayoutmanager);
        buyagift_recyclerview.setAdapter(buyAGiftAdapterFastItemAdapter);
        stickers();
    }

    private void stickers() {
        stickerarray.clear();
        OkHttpClient stickerclient = new OkHttpClient();
        Request stickerrequets = new Request.Builder().url(Constant.url + "gifts&facebook_id=" + Session.getUserID(getActivity())).build();
        final int position = getArguments().getInt("position", 1);
        stickerclient.newCall(stickerrequets).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Constant.l(e.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                try {
                    JSONObject startobj = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                    JSONObject giftobj = startobj.getJSONObject("giftcategories");
                    JSONArray giftarray = giftobj.getJSONArray("giftmenu");
                    JSONObject giftobjposition = giftarray.getJSONObject(position);
                    JSONArray stickerarrayobj = giftobjposition.getJSONArray("gifts");
                    for (int j = 0; j < stickerarrayobj.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject stickergiftimg = stickerarrayobj.getJSONObject(j);
                        StickerImage_Icon stickerImage = new StickerImage_Icon();
                        stickerImage.setSticker_iconimage(stickergiftimg.getString("image"));
                        stickerarray.add(stickerImage);
                    }

                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            buyAGiftAdapterFastItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Fragments Adapter

```
public class Buy_a_gift_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Buy_a_gift_adapter.Buyagift_viewholder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<StickerImage_Icon> stickerImages;

    public Buy_a_gift_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<StickerImage_Icon> stickerImages) {
        this.context = context;
        this.stickerImages = stickerImages;
    }

    @Override
    public Buyagift_viewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View buyagiftview = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.buy_a_gift_item, parent, false);
        return new Buyagift_viewholder(buyagiftview);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Buyagift_viewholder holder, int position) {
        StickerImage_Icon stickerImage = stickerImages.get(position);
        Glide.with(context).load(stickerImage.getSticker_iconimage()).into(holder.buy_image);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stickerImages.size();
    }

    public static class Buyagift_viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.buy_image)
        ImageView buy_image;

        public Buyagift_viewholder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Constant.l("Clicked");
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: why are you using runOnUiThread in OnResponse?

Comment: I think because we need to change text or adapter on the main thread na

Comment: onResponse works on UI thread only

Comment: No its giving me the Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.so i started using the runOnUiThread

Comment: you probabaly have intiatilizad chatclient in background thread or you are calling method in background

see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796850/retrofit-2-error-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: Please Check the code i had pasted the complete code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to change tab based on viewpager :

```
 viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
       tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: But when scroll the view pager tab is not selecting

Answer (score 1):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                sticker_tab.addTab(sticker_tab.newTab().setIcon(d));
                                Constant.l("Tab Count===>" + String.valueOf(sticker_tab.getTabCount()));
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Constant.l(e.toString());
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        chat_sticker_adapter = new Chat_Sticker_Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), giftarray);
                        sticker_pager.setAdapter(chat_sticker_adapter);
                        sticker_tab.setupWithViewPager(sticker_pager);
                    }
                });

combine this
```

Comment: here i had found a bug that when i comment this line sticker_tab.setupWithViewPager(sticker_pager); then everything is working fine but cant move the tab based on the viewpager changing

Answer (score 1):

Following this ViewPager implementation you can create tabs dynamically:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

//adapter view
androidAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(androidAdapter);
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int tabposition) {
            tabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(tabposition);
        }
    });

//        role = 1; //admin
//        role = 2; //master
        role = 3; //student

// Creating Dynamic TAB
    switch (role){
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            // MASTERLOGIN
            tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTab().setText("Slot History").setTabListener(this));
            tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTab().setText("Create Template").setTabListener(this));
            tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTab().setText("Scheduled").setTabListener(this));
            tabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            //--MASTERLOGIN
            break;
        case 3:
            //STUDENTLOGIN
            tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTab().setText("Products").setTabListener(this));
            tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTab().setText("Book A Slot").setTabListener(this));
            tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTab().setText("Scheduled").setTabListener(this));
            tabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            //--STUDENT LOGIN
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but your answer but the accept answer is user3040153 as he helped me solve issue from the core sorry

Comment: @orienlalxoxoorienlalxoxo It's ok! no issues but always follow the best approach.